# Optimisation problem on area of rectangle

Tags: calculus

A rectangle has a base on the $x$-axis and $2$ upper vertices on the parabola $y=12-x^2$. Find the largest area of this rectangle.

My answer is $16$ but the answer given is $32$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: You made a mistake

Comment: Can you add your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The length is 2x.

The width is $12-x^2$. However, this number is positive (“upper vertices”) so $0\le x\le 2\sqrt{3}$

The area is $a(x)=2x\cdot (12-x^2)=-2x^3+24x$

First derivative is zero:

$a’(x)=-6x^2+24=0\Rightarrow x=2$

Area is:

$a(2)=-2\cdot 2^3+ 24\cdot 2=32 units^2 (\therefore)$

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle bounded by $ -2 \leq x \leq 2$ has area $ 4 \times 8 = 32$, so the largest area is at least 32.
Thus, your answer is incorrect. You have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake.

Consider the rectangle with vertices $(-2,0), (2,0), (2,8),$ and $(-2,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a sketch you will see you need to maximize $\color{red}{2}x(12-x^2)$ and not $x(12-x^2)$.

Since the parabola is symmetric wrt. the $y$-axis, the width of the rectangle is $\color{red}{2}x$ instead of $x$.

This exactly is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you made a mistake, the area is $A=2x(12-x^2)$ and the max is at $x=2$, you probably took only half the rectangle in the first quadrant.